# Proof of accomodation for Spanish "Non-lucrative Residence Visa"

Tags: visas, spain

Is it possible to get a Spanish "Non-lucrative / Retirement Residence Visa" without providing a copy of a lease contract or property deed as proof of accommodation?

The application [instructions](http://www.exteriores.gob.es/Consulados/HOUSTON/es/ServiciosConsulares/Servicios_Consulares_Houston/Documents/Visado%20de%20residencia%20No%20lucrativa-%20Jubilaci%C3%B3n%20EN%20-%20Nuevo.pdf) state:

> If you have a property in Spain you need to provide the title deed of
>   property. In case of leasing or renting contract you must provide the
>   contract together with the copy of the landlord’s ID and copy of title
>   deed of property or property certificate.

My wife and I are planning to travel in Europe for 5 months, thus the need for the visa, but we are just staying in various AirBnB's the whole time.

What do you do if you're just staying in an AirBnB? Are you just out-of-luck?

Comment: During your 5-month trip in Europe, how long will you actually be staying in Spain?

Comment: We'll be in Spain approx. 4 months, but not sure exactly.